# Show that in a binary tree, if B is the number of branch points (including the root) and L is the number of leaves, then one has the relation L = 1+B

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, terminology, trees

We have been discussing trees lately, but have yet to even touch on the topic of a binary tree. I understand what a leaf is, but we didn't have one for the term "branch points" Without being 100% sure of what a branch point is, I didn't want to proceed with the proof.

Comment: A branch point is a vertex / node in the tree with two children.

Answer (score 1):

It is true for all trees with only one node (a leaf):

$$L = 1,\ B=0$$

At a branch node $N$, if both of its child subtrees satisfy the equation,
$$L_1=1+B_1,\ L_2 = 1+B_2$$
(where the subscripts denote each of the two subtrees), then counting the subtree rooted at $N$, the total number of branch nodes is
$$B_1+B_2+1$$
and the total number of leaves is
$$\begin{align*}
L_1+L_2 &= (1+B_1)+(1+B_2)\\
&= 1+ (B_1+B_2+1)
\end{align*}$$

By induction from the leaves to the root, the whole binary tree satisfies the relation $L=1+B$.